# Julia 1.7.1 on M1 fails on `Pkg.build()`

Tags: julia, apple-m1

```
ERROR: Error building `NNlib`: 
┌ Warning: Platform `arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0` is not an officially supported platform
└ @ BinaryProvider ~/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/U2dKK/src/PlatformNames.jl:450
ERROR: LoadError: KeyError: key "unknown" not found
```

How to solve the issue or at least fix the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Running Julia natively on MacOS on ARM chips, such as the M1, currently has only ["Tier 3" support](https://julialang.org/downloads/#support_tiers_for_the_latest_stable_release_of_julia). This means

> Tier 3: Julia may or may not build. If it does, it is unlikely to pass tests. Binaries may be available in some cases. When they are, they should be considered experimental. Ongoing support is dependent on community efforts.

For individual packages, if they have binary dependencies, it depends on how those are provided. If they are provided by the modern BinaryBuilder.jl / Yggdrasil.jl infrastructure, those binary dependencies may be available for `arm64-apple-darwin`; if they use some older system for binary dependencies, that will almost certainly not support Mac on ARM.

In the meanwhile, you might instead use the `macOS x86 (Intel or Rosetta)` release from https://julialang.org/downloads/ for production work; this should cause both Julia itself and any package binary dependencies to run using x86 binaries via Rosetta, and should generally work without error on M1.

Comment: One should also distinguish between Julia itself and packages. Julia itself supports M1 as a tier 3 platform. Arbitrary packages from the ecosystem might not (yet) support M1 at all.

Comment: The error of the OP is not related to Julia itself but seems to be triggered by BinaryProvider.jl which, given that the last commit is from early 2020 and therefore months before M1 was released, clearly doesn't support M1.

Comment: Is it possible to have both `arm64` and `x64` versions installed?

Comment: That should be possible, yes